# ASP Health-UI render in Blazor Component

Tags: asp.net, blazor

Xabaril provides an easy way to show the health in an UI: https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.
When I open the url localhost/health-ui I see the health page.

I would like to embed this page in a blazor component, because it should appear inside the layout.
The only way is in my mind is going over iFrames.
I just wonder if there is an elegant way to go.

Thanks in advance

I tried I frames but its messy